# How to delete an object from Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, parse-server

I would like to delete an object from Parse when I un-check the table row.

The issue occurs when trying to delete objects from Parse after having queried them.

**this is my code:**

```
   if  cell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None

            var query = PFQuery(className:"Followers")
            query.whereKey("follower", equalTo: "\(PFUser.currentUser()?.username)")
            query.whereKey("following", equalTo: "\(cell.textLabel?.text)")

            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    for object in objects as! [PFUser] {

                        object.deleteInBackground()
                    }

                } else {
                    println(error)
                }
            }


        }
```

Comment: Can you use Xcode to place a breakpoint to see if `deleteInBackground` is getting called?

Comment: i checked with println and it "s not getting called...

Comment: Can you check that `objects.count != 0`? Or can you atleast see what is getting called?

Comment: yes i println objects and the objects appeares...

Comment: Do your user class ACLs permit this operation?

Comment: Wait you said that `deleteInBackground ` is not getting called right? That would mean that `error  != nil` or your for loop isn't working, since you said that `objects` isn't empty.

Comment: but the error didn't print anything...

Comment: @thefredelement how to check that my class allow this...

Comment: the ACL column on your PFUser class will tell you what is allowed

Comment: the for loop didn't work is there any other way to do it...

Comment: @kdogisthebest objects.count == 0 what should i do...

Comment: @thefredelement the Acl is public and read only what should i do to fix  it

Comment: If it's count is 0 than the query couldn't find anything in the table. Either that or your query is wrong

Answer (score 4):

I think the issue is in your query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock
i think its because you are defining objects as! [PFUser] instead of a [PFObject]

try this it should do the trick

```
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects, error) in
        if error == nil,
            let objects = objects {
            for object in objects {
                object.deleteInBackground()
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to delete objects from parse

Yes in the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) to delete multiple objects in background at once on [Parse server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server), you can use [deleteAllInBackground](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(cm)deleteAllInBackground:block:)

You can use it with 2 different ways:

```
PFObject.deleteAll(inBackground: [PFObject]?)
PFObject.deleteAll(inBackground: [PFObject]?, block: PFBooleanResultBlock?)
```

For example:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
    PFObject.deleteAll(inBackground: objects)
})
```

You can also see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43313901/swift-delete-multiple-objects-at-once-parse-server/43316430#43316430)

I hope my answer was helpful