# Swift Delete multiple objects at once Parse server

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server

I query to the server following

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
            query.whereKey("uuid", equalTo: Ncell.uuidLbl.text!)
            query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) in
                if error == nil {
                    for object in objects! {
                        object.deleteInBackground(block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) in
                            if success{

                            }
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
```

Rather than using a loop and deleting each object individually, I want to know if it would be possible to delete all the found objects at once to save on requests.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's a method that deletes multiple objects, look for it in the definition of `PFObject`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I want to know if it would be possible to delete all the found objects at once

Yes in the [Parse iOS SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX) to delete multiple objects in background at once on [Parse server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server), you can use [deleteAllInBackground](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/api/Classes/PFObject.html#/c:objc(cs)PFObject(cm)deleteAllInBackground:block:)

You can use it with 2 different ways:

```
PFObject.deleteAll(inBackground: [PFObject]?)
PFObject.deleteAll(inBackground: [PFObject]?, block: PFBooleanResultBlock?)
```

For example:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "posts")
query.whereKey("uuid", equalTo: Ncell.uuidLbl.text!)
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:Error?) in
    if error == nil {
        PFObject.deleteAll(inBackground: objects, block: { (success:Bool, error:Error?) in
                if success {

                }
            })
        }
    }
```

I hope my answer was helpful